# Possible techniques used to find intersection of lines

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am currently trying to find the intersection between the lines.

[image: lines]

Are there any possible techniques in MATLAB to determine these points, since the `x` and `y` coordinates are not a function of `f`?

Comment: Possibly [`polyxpoly`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/polyxpoly.html)? I've not used it before but the examples looks like what you're trying to do

Comment: The equation of the intersection of 2 lines (mathematically speaking) is *very very easy*. Creating lines from points is *very very easy*. Combine!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Bentley–Ottmann algorithm` Sweepline algorithm of time complexity O((N + K) log N). But as far as I know, it is not built-in in Matlab.

However, there is a decent Pseudo-Code for it [Here](http://geomalgorithms.com/a09-_intersect-3.html).